# How to block Trinity.txt.bak calls in nginx

Tags: django, nginx

I am runnning some web servers using nginx as a proxy in front of django applications. Every now and then I see calls to

> https://*.[MY.DOMAIN]/nice%20ports,/Trinity.txt.bak

being passed to Django which generates the exception "Invalid HTTP_HOST header". How can I block these kind of requests in nginx so they never reach Django?